# Joomla 3 Jfactory get user php code stuck logged in

Tags: php, html, joomla

I have tried making code to tell a user that they need to be logged in to view a link, and part of the link will also be generated by Jfactory, I am writing this code on a separate php file and I have tried all sorts of things from stackoverflow, and I keep getting you are logged in and can get different results here is my code:

```
    <?php
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
    $rootFolder = explode(DS,dirname(__FILE__));
    //current level in diretoty structure
    $currentfolderlevel = 9;
    array_splice($rootFolder,-$currentfolderlevel);
    $base_folder = implode(DS,$rootFolder);
    if(is_dir($base_folder.DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'))   
    {
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE',implode(DS,$rootFolder));
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
    $userid='';
    $usertype='';
    $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $mainframe->initialise();
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $userid = $user->get('id');
    $usertype = $user->get('usertype');
    }
    if ($user->guest) {
    echo 'You are not logged in';
    } else {
    echo 'You are logged in';
    }
    ?>
```

Also my joomla version is Joomla 3.2.4 and the url to the code i am referring to is https://wgalive.com/teamspeakinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to my problem I had to install an extension to embed php code into my article on joomla: Sourcerer Code Helper and then had to use the following code and it worked:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') OR die("Restricted access"); // Prevent direct Access to the program
$user =& JFactory::getUser(); // get user
if ($user->guest) {
echo "<h3>Please log in to see your teamspeak login link! </h3>"; // Show this message if user not yet log in
} else {

echo "<h3>Hello {$user->name}! Below is a link to logging into our teamspeak server with your username!</h3>";

echo '<p><a href="ts3server://srv.wgalive.com?port=9987&nickname='.$user->username.'&password=passwordhere&addbookmark=WGA-Server">Login to Teamspeak</a></p>';



}
?>
```